# Pandas add increment to timestamp to break ties, preserving original order

Tags: pandas, timedelta

I have a dataframe of the format

```
   df = pandas.DataFrame([{'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:42:13.582500', 'value' : 1},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:43:28.937400', 'value':   2},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:43:28.937400', 'value' :   -1},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:43:28.937400', 'value' :   2},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:43:28.937400', 'value' :   -4},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:43:37.237500', 'value' :    1},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:43:37.237500', 'value' :    1},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:43:37.237500', 'value' :    1},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:47:25.470300', 'value' :    3},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:47:54.791500', 'value' :    4},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:49:11.971600', 'value' :   5},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:49:11.971600', 'value' :    2},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:49:33.285500', 'value' :    1},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:49:42.414700', 'value' :   10},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:49:55.300300', 'value' :   11},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:49:55.300300', 'value' :    9},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:52:03.992600', 'value' :   -1},
    {'tstamp':'2019-03-06 06:52:03.992600', 'value' :    2}])
```

Some of the index timestamps have ties in them.

My question is: How can I efficiently add just enough timedelta to the index of the rows with a tie, to break the ties in index whilst preserving the order of the data?

@jezrael:

I need a to create a new 'tstamp' columns, let's call it 'tstamp2', that satisfies these conditions:

- `(df.sort_values('tstamp2').index == df.sort_values('tstamp').index).all()` be True,
- `df.tstamp2.duplicated().any()` be False,
- `(df[~df.tstamp.duplicated()].tstamp == df[~df.tstamp.duplicated()].tstamp2).all()` be True,

Comment: Is possible add expected output?

Comment: @jezrael: the solution is not unique. But all acceptable solutions must satisfies the trio of conditions I have added to the question. Does it help?

Comment: Do you want the timestamps to be strings or is a conversion to a timestamp format ok?

Comment: Conversion to timestamp certainly ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a conversion of `'tstamp'` to `np.datetime` format is ok, then this should work:

```
df['tstamp2'] = pandas.to_datetime(df.tstamp)
df['tstamp2'] += pandas.to_timedelta(df.groupby(df.tstamp2).cumcount(), unit='ns')
# Condition 1:
# Out: True
# Condition 2:
# Out: False
# Condition 3:
# Out: True
```

Assuming "just enough timedelta" is a nanosecond (`unit='ns'`).

If you want to preserve `'tstamp'` as strings, your task can be achieved like this:

```
df['tstamp2'] = df.tstamp + df.groupby(df.tstamp).cumcount().astype(str)
# Condition 1:
# Out: True
# Condition 2:
# Out: False
# Condition 3:
# Out: True
```

Both methods satisfy all three conditions.